# Convert XML to table SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I wonder how I can read a XML data and transform it to a table in T-SQL?

For example:

```
<t1>
      <t2>
        <val>Opel</val>
        <t3>Merriva</t3>
        <t3>Zafira</t3>
      </t2>
      <t2>
        <val>Fiat</val>
        <t3>Albea</t3>
      </t2>
  </t1>
```

To:

Table1:

```
id      value
----------------
1        Opel
2        Fiat
```

Table2:

```
id      id_Table1       value
-----------------------------------
1          1            Merriva
2          1            Zafira
3          2            Albea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an active SQL-Server 2005 to test this (boy, it's 2018...!!!), but I think, that this query would work in such ancient versions too:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<t1>
    <t2>
    <val>Opel</val>
    <t3>Merriva</t3>
    <t3>Zafira</t3>
    </t2>
    <t2>
    <val>Fiat</val>
    <t3>Albea</t3>
    </t2>
</t1>';

--The CTE will return the CarName with a running index together with the related data as XML-node
WITH Cars AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS t2_index
        ,t2.value(N'(val/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(100)') AS t2_val
        ,t2.query(N't3') AS t3_nodes
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/t1/t2') A(t2)
)
--This part will append all related data with a running number for the related type data
SELECT Cars.* 
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS CarValueIndex
    ,t3.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(100)') AS CarValue
INTO #tmpCars --write the result into a temp table
FROM Cars
OUTER APPLY t3_nodes.nodes(N't3') A(t3);

--All data de-normalized
SELECT * FROM #tmpCars;

--This query will bring back the parent rows
SELECT t2_index AS CarID
      ,t2_val AS CarName
FROM #tmpCars
GROUP BY t2_index,t2_val;

--And this query will return the related child data
SELECT CarValueIndex AS CarTypeID
      ,t2_index AS fk_CarID
      ,CarValue AS CarType
FROM #tmpCars;

GO
DROP TABLE #tmpCars;
```

If there is any chance to move to a more modern SQL-Server you really should do it...

### UPDATE

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), the `.value()` and `.nodes()` function were introduced with v2008. But I have a dark memory, that it was working in 2005 already, might be together with some service packs... Try it out.